# Ubuntu One on Windows: pointing to the right Desktop

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-one-windows

Ubuntu One syncs my Ubuntu "Desktop" folder in the cloud, named "Bureau" (French) with path `/home/username/Bureau`. Ubuntu One on Windows 8 syncs this folder with a Windows 8 folder `C:\Users\user_000\Bureau`, created by the Ubuntu One sync. However, in Windows 8, the default folder for the desktop view is `C:\Users\user_000\Desktop`. Is this a bug or a configuration option in Ubuntu One?

Thanks.

Comment: An option is to change the location of the Desktop folder in Windows 8. http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/14719-screenshots-change-default-folder-location-windows-8-a.html

Comment: I think this is happen because you installed Ubuntu One in franch language and Windows 8 is in english.

Comment: @Radu Both installations are in French. As far as I know, paths in Windows 8 are langage independant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using translated folder names for standard folders on Ubuntu. Ubuntu One does not rename folders when syncing to other devices. You will need to reconfigure your Windows system to point at the same folder, just sync both folders, or reconfigure Ubuntu to use untranslated folder names.